# How to display date and time in text widget of flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display date and time in text widget of flutter with the help of `import 'package:intl/intl.dart';` package, but its throwing and error.

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
>
> The method 'toDate' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: toDate()

```
Row(
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
 children: [
    Text('Order Date: ${DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(data['createdAt'].toDate())}'),
    Text('Order Time: ${DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(data['createdAt'].toDate())}'),
],),
```

Comment: could you provide your time and date

Comment: He doesn't have a date, it's null.  I think the question is how to display a null date?

Answer (score 2):

the **toDate()** method is available in the **string_validator** package. I think you should use the default **DateTime.parse()** and use it as:

```dart
var parsedDate = DateTime.parse(data['createdAt']);
```

Then run it through the DateFormat as:

```dart
DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(parsedDate))
```

Comment: I have tried it already with this. it is throwing an error **type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String'**